# Aggregate Overlapping Segments to Measure Effective Length

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle12c, asset-management

I have a `road_events` table:

```
create table road_events (
    event_id number(4,0),
    road_id number(4,0),
    year number(4,0),
    from_meas number(10,2),
    to_meas number(10,2),
    total_road_length number(10,2)
    );

insert into road_events (event_id, road_id, year, from_meas, to_meas, total_road_length) values (1,1,2020,25,50,100);
insert into road_events (event_id, road_id, year, from_meas, to_meas, total_road_length) values (2,1,2000,25,50,100);
insert into road_events (event_id, road_id, year, from_meas, to_meas, total_road_length) values (3,1,1980,0,25,100);
insert into road_events (event_id, road_id, year, from_meas, to_meas, total_road_length) values (4,1,1960,75,100,100);
insert into road_events (event_id, road_id, year, from_meas, to_meas, total_road_length) values (5,1,1940,1,100,100);

insert into road_events (event_id, road_id, year, from_meas, to_meas, total_road_length) values (6,2,2000,10,30,100);
insert into road_events (event_id, road_id, year, from_meas, to_meas, total_road_length) values (7,2,1975,30,60,100);
insert into road_events (event_id, road_id, year, from_meas, to_meas, total_road_length) values (8,2,1950,50,90,100);

insert into road_events (event_id, road_id, year, from_meas, to_meas, total_road_length) values (9,3,2050,40,90,100);

insert into road_events (event_id, road_id, year, from_meas, to_meas, total_road_length) values (10,4,2040,0,200,200);
insert into road_events (event_id, road_id, year, from_meas, to_meas, total_road_length) values (11,4,2013,0,199,200);
insert into road_events (event_id, road_id, year, from_meas, to_meas, total_road_length) values (12,4,2001,0,200,200);

insert into road_events (event_id, road_id, year, from_meas, to_meas, total_road_length) values (13,5,1985,50,70,300);
insert into road_events (event_id, road_id, year, from_meas, to_meas, total_road_length) values (14,5,1985,10,50,300);
insert into road_events (event_id, road_id, year, from_meas, to_meas, total_road_length) values (15,5,1965,1,301,300);
commit;

select * from road_events;
```

---

```
  EVENT_ID    ROAD_ID       YEAR  FROM_MEAS    TO_MEAS TOTAL_ROAD_LENGTH
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -----------------
         1          1       2020         25         50               100
         2          1       2000         25         50               100
         3          1       1980          0         25               100
         4          1       1960         75        100               100
         5          1       1940          1        100               100

         6          2       2000         10         30               100
         7          2       1975         30         60               100
         8          2       1950         50         90               100

         9          3       2050         40         90               100

        10          4       2040          0        200               200
        11          4       2013          0        199               200
        12          4       2001          0        200               200

        13          5       1985         50         70               300
        14          5       1985         10         50               300
        15          5       1965          1        301               300
```

---

**I want to select the events that represent the most recent work on each road.**

This is a tricky operation, because the events **often pertain to only a portion of the road**. This means that I can't simply select the most recent event per road; I need to only select the most recent ***event mileage*** that doesn't overlap.

---

**Possible logic (in order):**

*I'm reluctant to guess at how this problem could be solved, because it could end up hurting more than it helps (kind of like the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)). On the other hand, it might provide insight into the nature of the problem, so here it goes:*

1. Select the most recent event for each road. We'll call the most recent event: `event A`.
2. If `event A`  is `>= total_road_length`, then that's all I need. The algorithm ends here.
3. Else, get the next chronological event (`event B`) that does not have the same extents as `event A`.
4. If the extents of `event B` overlap the extents of `event A`, then only get the portion(s) of `event B` that do not overlap.
5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 until the total event length is `= total_road_length`. Or stop when there are no more events for that road.

---

**Question:**

I know it's a tall order, but **what would it take to do this?**

*This is a classic **linear referencing** problem. It would be extremely helpful if I could do linear referencing operations as part of queries.*

The result would be:

```
  EVENT_ID    ROAD_ID       YEAR  TOTAL_ROAD_LENGTH   EVENT_LENGTH
---------- ---------- ----------  -----------------   ------------
         1          1       2020                100             25
         3          1       1980                100             25
         4          1       1960                100             25
         5          1       1940                100             25

         6          2       2000                100             20
         7          2       1975                100             30
         8          2       1950                100             30

         9          3       2050                100             50

        10          4       2040                200            200

        13          5       1985                300             20
        14          5       1985                300             40
        15          5       1965                300            240
```

Related question: [Select where number range does not overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51729896/select-where-number-range-does-not-overlap)

Comment: What should be returned if one event is from 10-100 year 2010 and another 20-40 year 2020, three rows 10-20/2010, 20-40/2020, 40-100/2010?

Comment: @dnoeth Good catch. I hadn't thought of that. `Option 1 (dnoeth's option):`  Returning 3 rows would be fine; it's the most explicit option. `Option 2:` However, in hindsight, I don't think it's really necessary to return the `from_meas` and `to_meas` as part of the query. But it **is necessary** to know the length of the events that are returned. Therefore, we could just return an `event_length` column, which would be an aggregate of `10-20/2010` and `40-100/2010`. And of course, a row for `20-40/2020`.

Comment: I think this can be done with analytics functions and windowing. You've got a lot of criteria. The tricky part will be dealing with overlaps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My main DBMS is Teradata, but this will work as-is in Oracle, too.

```
WITH all_meas AS
 ( -- get a distinct list of all from/to points
   SELECT road_id, from_meas AS meas
   FROM road_events
   UNION
   SELECT road_id, to_meas
   FROM road_events
 )
-- select * from all_meas order by 1,2
 , all_ranges AS
 ( -- create from/to ranges
   SELECT road_id, meas AS from_meas 
     ,Lead(meas)
      Over (PARTITION BY road_id
            ORDER BY meas) AS to_meas
   FROM all_meas
  )
 -- SELECT * from all_ranges order by 1,2
, all_event_ranges AS
 ( -- now match the ranges to the event ranges
   SELECT 
      ar.*
     ,re.event_id
     ,re.year
     ,re.total_road_length
     ,ar.to_meas - ar.from_meas AS event_length
     -- used to filter the latest event as multiple events might cover the same range 
     ,Row_Number()
      Over (PARTITION BY ar.road_id, ar.from_meas
            ORDER BY year DESC) AS rn
   FROM all_ranges ar
   JOIN road_events re
     ON ar.road_id = re.road_id
    AND ar.from_meas < re.to_meas
    AND ar.to_meas > re.from_meas
   WHERE ar.to_meas IS NOT NULL
 )
SELECT event_id, road_id, year, total_road_length, Sum(event_length)
FROM all_event_ranges
WHERE rn = 1 -- latest year only
GROUP BY event_id, road_id, year, total_road_length
ORDER BY road_id, year DESC;
```

If you need to return the actual covered `from/to_meas` (as in your question before edit), it might be more complicated. The first part is the same, but without aggregation the query can return adjacent rows with the same event_id (e.g. for event 3: 0-1 & 1-25):

```
SELECT * FROM all_event_ranges
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY road_id, from_meas;
```

If you want to merge adjacent rows you need two more steps (using a standard approach, flag the 1st row of a group and calculate a group number):

```
WITH all_meas AS
 (
   SELECT road_id, from_meas AS meas
   FROM road_events
   UNION
   SELECT road_id, to_meas
   FROM road_events
 )
-- select * from all_meas order by 1,2
 , all_ranges AS
 ( 
   SELECT road_id, meas AS from_meas 
     ,Lead(meas)
      Over (PARTITION BY road_id
            ORDER BY meas) AS to_meas
   FROM all_meas
  )
-- SELECT * from all_ranges order by 1,2
, all_event_ranges AS
 (
   SELECT 
      ar.*
     ,re.event_id
     ,re.year
     ,re.total_road_length
     ,ar.to_meas - ar.from_meas AS event_length
     ,Row_Number()
      Over (PARTITION BY ar.road_id, ar.from_meas
            ORDER BY year DESC) AS rn
   FROM all_ranges ar
   JOIN road_events  re
     ON ar.road_id = re.road_id
    AND ar.from_meas < re.to_meas
    AND ar.to_meas > re.from_meas
   WHERE ar.to_meas IS NOT NULL
 )
-- SELECT * FROM all_event_ranges WHERE rn = 1 ORDER BY road_id, from_meas
, adjacent_events AS 
 ( -- assign 1 to the 1st row of an event
   SELECT t.*
     ,CASE WHEN Lag(event_id)
                Over(PARTITION BY road_id
                     ORDER BY from_meas) = event_id
           THEN 0 
           ELSE 1 
      END AS flag
   FROM all_event_ranges t
   WHERE rn = 1
 )
-- SELECT * FROM adjacent_events ORDER BY road_id, from_meas 
, grouped_events AS
 ( -- assign a groupnumber to adjacent rows using a Cumulative Sum over 0/1
   SELECT t.*
     ,Sum(flag)
      Over (PARTITION BY road_id
            ORDER BY from_meas
            ROWS Unbounded Preceding) AS grp
   FROM adjacent_events t
)
-- SELECT * FROM grouped_events ORDER BY  road_id, from_meas
SELECT event_id, road_id, year, Min(from_meas), Max(to_meas), total_road_length, Sum(event_length)
FROM grouped_events
GROUP BY event_id, road_id, grp, year, total_road_length
ORDER BY 2, Min(from_meas);
```

Edit:

Ups, I just found a blog [Overlapping ranges with priority](https://stewashton.wordpress.com/2014/03/22/overlapping-ranges-with-priority/) doing exactly the same with some simplified Oracle syntax. In fact I translated my query from a some other simplified syntax in Teradata to Standard/Oracle SQL :-)

Comment: Based on your experience with your queries, do you have any recommendations as to which columns to index in the table?

Comment: You don't need many indexes in Teradata, but the join in `all_event_ranges` was using most resources, thus indexing `road_id` , myabe adding `from_meas` and `to_meas`...

Answer (score 5):

There is another way to calculate this, with from and to values:

```
with 
  part_begin_point as (
    Select distinct road_id, from_meas point
    from road_events be
    union 
    Select distinct road_id, to_meas point
    from road_events ee
  )
, newest_part as (
  select e.event_id
  , e.road_id
  , e.year
  , e.total_road_length
  , p.point
  , LAG(e.event_id) over (partition by p.road_id order by p.point) prev_event
  , e.to_meas event_to_meas
  from part_begin_point p
  join road_events e
   on p.road_id = e.road_id
   and p.point >= e.from_meas and  p.point < e.to_meas
   and not exists(
        select 1 from road_events ne 
        where e.road_id = ne.road_id
        and p.point >= ne.from_meas and p.point < ne.to_meas
        and (e.year < ne.year or e.year = ne.year and e.event_id < ne.event_id))
  )
select event_id, road_id, year
, point from_meas
, LEAD(point, 1, event_to_meas) over (partition by road_id order by point) to_meas
, total_road_length
, LEAD(point, 1, event_to_meas) over (partition by road_id order by point) - point EVENT_LENGTH
from newest_part
where 1=1
and event_id <> prev_event or prev_event is null
order by event_id, point
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/50a71/140/0)

Answer (score 4):

Thought about this too much today, but I have something that ignores the +/- 10 meters now.

First made a function that takes in to / from pairs as a string and returns the distance covered by the pairs in the string. For example '10:20;35:45' returns 20.

```
CREATE
    OR replace FUNCTION get_distance_range_str (strRangeStr VARCHAR2)

RETURN NUMBER IS intRetNum NUMBER;

BEGIN
    --split input string
    WITH cte_1
    AS (
        SELECT regexp_substr(strRangeStr, '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL) AS TO_FROM_STRING
        FROM dual connect BY regexp_substr(strRangeStr, '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
        )
        --split From/To pairs
        ,cte_2
    AS (
        SELECT cte_1.TO_FROM_STRING
            ,to_number(substr(cte_1.TO_FROM_STRING, 1, instr(cte_1.TO_FROM_STRING, ':') - 1)) AS FROM_MEAS
            ,to_number(substr(cte_1.TO_FROM_STRING, instr(cte_1.TO_FROM_STRING, ':') + 1, length(cte_1.TO_FROM_STRING) - instr(cte_1.TO_FROM_STRING, ':'))) AS TO_MEAS
        FROM cte_1
        )
        --merge ranges
        ,cte_merge_ranges
    AS (
        SELECT s1.FROM_MEAS
            ,
            --t1.TO_MEAS 
            MIN(t1.TO_MEAS) AS TO_MEAS
        FROM cte_2 s1
        INNER JOIN cte_2 t1 ON s1.FROM_MEAS <= t1.TO_MEAS
            AND NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM cte_2 t2
                WHERE t1.TO_MEAS >= t2.FROM_MEAS
                    AND t1.TO_MEAS < t2.TO_MEAS
                )
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM cte_2 s2
                WHERE s1.FROM_MEAS > s2.FROM_MEAS
                    AND s1.FROM_MEAS <= s2.TO_MEAS
                )
        GROUP BY s1.FROM_MEAS
        )
    SELECT sum(TO_MEAS - FROM_MEAS) AS DISTANCE_COVERED
    INTO intRetNum
    FROM cte_merge_ranges;

    RETURN intRetNum;
END;
```

Then wrote this query that builds a string for that function for the appropriate prior range. Couldn't use windowing with list_agg, but was able to achieve same with a correlated subquery.

```
--use list agg to create list of to/from pairs for rows before current row in the ordering
WITH cte_2
AS (
    SELECT T1.*
        ,(
            SELECT LISTAGG(FROM_MEAS || ':' || TO_MEAS || ';') WITHIN
            GROUP (
                    ORDER BY ORDER BY YEAR DESC, EVENT_ID DESC
                    )
            FROM road_events T2
            WHERE T1.YEAR || lpad(T1.EVENT_ID, 10,'0') < 
                T2.YEAR || lpad(T2.EVENT_ID, 10,'0')
                AND T1.ROAD_ID = T2.ROAD_ID
            GROUP BY road_id
            ) AS PRIOR_RANGES_STR
    FROM road_events T1
    )
    --get distance for prior range string - distance ignoring current row
    --get distance including current row
    ,cte_3
AS (
    SELECT cte_2.*
        ,coalesce(get_distance_range_str(PRIOR_RANGES_STR), 0) AS DIST_PRIOR
        ,get_distance_range_str(PRIOR_RANGES_STR || FROM_MEAS || ':' || TO_MEAS || ';') AS DIST_NOW
    FROM cte_2 cte_2
    )
    --distance including current row less distance ignoring current row is distance added to the range this row
    ,cte_4
AS (
    SELECT cte_3.*
        ,DIST_NOW - DIST_PRIOR AS DIST_ADDED_THIS_ROW
    FROM cte_3
    )
SELECT *
FROM cte_4
--filter out any rows with distance added as 0
WHERE DIST_ADDED_THIS_ROW > 0
ORDER BY ROAD_ID, YEAR DESC, EVENT_ID DESC
```

sqlfiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/81331/36

Looks to me like the results match yours. I left the additional columns in the final query to try to illustrate each step.

Works on the test case - might need some work to handle all possibilities in a larger data set, but I think this would be a good place to start and refine.

Credit for Overlapping range merge is first answer here: [Merge overlapping date intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561130/merge-overlapping-date-intervals)

Credit for list_agg with windowing is first answer here:
[LISTAGG equivalent with windowing clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952950/listagg-equivalent-with-windowing-clause)

Comment: I think eliminating the <10 rows might be as simple as changing the 0 at the end to 10 of the query.

Comment: Re-reading the problem, I didn't build this to strictly meet your criteria - kind of read-between the lines and solved "when was each mile of road last worked on?".

Comment: Cool - added a bit to apply an ordering of YEAR DESC, EVENT_ID DESC to better handle the case with multiple events in the same year on the same row.

Comment: What's the difference between `Select events that represent the most recent work on roads` and `when was each mile of road last worked on?` ?

Comment: Nothing - I was referring to the proposed logic section with that. Some of the rules read like you're comparing 2 rows only. I was also confused by the tolerances which indicated the sum could be greater than the length of the road, so I thought I may have misinterpreted some of those rules. Guess I didn't read between the lines so much as read the question, review the proposed logic, then ignored the proposed logic part of the post.

Answer (score 4):

I had a problem with your "road events", because of you don't describe what is 1st `meas`, I posit it is period between 0 and 1 without 1.

so, you can count this with one query:

```
with newest_MEAS as (
select ROAD_ID, MEAS.m, max(year) y
from road_events
join (select rownum -1 m 
      from dual 
      connect by rownum -1 <= (select max(TOTAL_ROAD_LENGTH) from road_events) ) MEAS
  on MEAS.m between FROM_MEAS and TO_MEAS
group by ROAD_ID, MEAS.m )
select re.event_id, nm.ROAD_ID, re.total_road_length, nm.y, count(nm.m) EVENT_LENGTH
from newest_MEAS nm
join road_events re 
  on nm.ROAD_ID = re.ROAD_ID
  and nm.m between re.from_meas and re.to_meas -1
  and nm.y = re.year
group by re.event_id, nm.ROAD_ID, re.total_road_length, nm.y
order by event_id
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/50a71/106)

Answer (score 4):

**Solution:**

```
SELECT RE.road_id, RE.event_id, RE.year, RE.from_meas, RE.to_meas, RE.road_length, RE.event_length, RE.used_length, RE.leftover_length
  FROM
  (
    SELECT RE.C_road_id[road_id], RE.C_event_id[event_id], RE.C_year[year], RE.C_from_meas[from_meas], RE.C_to_meas[to_meas], RE.C_road_length[road_length],
           RE.event_length, RE.used_length, (RE.event_length - (CASE WHEN RE.HasOverlap = 1 THEN RE.used_length ELSE 0 END))[leftover_length]
      FROM
      (
        SELECT RE.C_road_id, RE.C_event_id, RE.C_year, RE.C_from_meas, RE.C_to_meas, RE.C_road_length,
               (CASE WHEN MAX(RE.A_event_id) IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)[HasOverlap],
               (RE.C_to_meas - RE.C_from_meas)[event_length],
               SUM(   (CASE WHEN RE.O_to_meas <= RE.C_to_meas THEN RE.O_to_meas ELSE RE.C_to_meas END)
                    - (CASE WHEN RE.O_from_meas >= RE.C_from_meas THEN RE.O_from_meas ELSE RE.C_from_meas END)
                  )[used_length]--This is the length that is already being counted towards later years.
          FROM
          (
            SELECT RE.C_road_id, RE.C_event_id, RE.C_year, RE.C_from_meas, RE.C_to_meas, RE.C_road_length,
                   RE.A_event_id, MIN(RE.O_from_meas)[O_from_meas], MAX(RE.O_to_meas)[O_to_meas]
              FROM
              (
                SELECT RE_C.road_id[C_road_id], RE_C.event_id[C_event_id], RE_C.year[C_year], RE_C.from_meas[C_from_meas], RE_C.to_meas[C_to_meas], RE_C.total_road_length[C_road_length],
                       RE_A.road_id[A_road_id], RE_A.event_id[A_event_id], RE_A.year[A_year], RE_A.from_meas[A_from_meas], RE_A.to_meas[A_to_meas], RE_A.total_road_length[A_road_length],
                       RE_O.road_id[O_road_id], RE_O.event_id[O_event_id], RE_O.year[O_year], RE_O.from_meas[O_from_meas], RE_O.to_meas[O_to_meas], RE_O.total_road_length[O_road_length],
                       (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RE_C.road_id, RE_C.event_id, RE_O.event_id ORDER BY RE_S.Overlap DESC, RE_A.event_id))[RowNum]--Use to Group Overlaps into Swaths.
                  FROM road_events as RE_C--Current.
                  LEFT JOIN road_events as RE_A--After.  --Use a Left-Join to capture when there is only 1 Event (or it is the Last-Event in the list).
                    ON RE_A.road_id   = RE_C.road_id
                   AND RE_A.event_id != RE_C.event_id--Not the same EventID.
                   AND RE_A.year     >= RE_C.year--Occured on or After the Current Event.
                   AND (    (RE_A.from_meas >= RE_C.from_meas AND RE_A.from_meas <= RE_C.to_meas)--There is Overlap.
                         OR (RE_A.to_meas   >= RE_C.from_meas AND RE_A.to_meas   <= RE_C.to_meas)--There is Overlap.
                         OR (RE_A.to_meas    = RE_C.to_meas   AND RE_A.from_meas  = RE_C.from_meas)--They are Equal.
                       )
                  LEFT JOIN road_events as RE_O--Overlapped/Linked.
                    ON RE_O.road_id   = RE_C.road_id
                   AND RE_O.event_id != RE_C.event_id--Not the same EventID.
                   AND RE_O.year     >= RE_C.year--Occured on or After the Current Event.
                   AND (    (RE_O.from_meas >= RE_A.from_meas AND RE_O.from_meas <= RE_A.to_meas)--There is Overlap.
                         OR (RE_O.to_meas   >= RE_A.from_meas AND RE_O.to_meas   <= RE_A.to_meas)--There is Overlap.
                         OR (RE_O.to_meas    = RE_A.to_meas   AND RE_O.from_meas  = RE_A.from_meas)--They are Equal.
                       )
                  OUTER APPLY
                  (
                    SELECT COUNT(*)[Overlap]
                      FROM road_events as RE_O--Overlapped/Linked.
                     WHERE RE_O.road_id   = RE_C.road_id
                       AND RE_O.event_id != RE_C.event_id--Not the same EventID.
                       AND RE_O.year     >= RE_C.year--Occured on or After the Current Event.
                       AND (    (RE_O.from_meas >= RE_A.from_meas AND RE_O.from_meas <= RE_A.to_meas)--There is Overlap.
                             OR (RE_O.to_meas   >= RE_A.from_meas AND RE_O.to_meas   <= RE_A.to_meas)--There is Overlap.
                             OR (RE_O.to_meas    = RE_A.to_meas   AND RE_O.from_meas  = RE_A.from_meas)--They are Equal.
                           )
                  ) AS RE_S--Swath of Overlaps.
              ) AS RE
             WHERE RE.RowNum = 1--Remove Duplicates and Select those that are in the biggest Swaths.
             GROUP BY RE.C_road_id, RE.C_event_id, RE.C_year, RE.C_from_meas, RE.C_to_meas, RE.C_road_length,
                      RE.A_event_id
          ) AS RE
         GROUP BY RE.C_road_id, RE.C_event_id, RE.C_year, RE.C_from_meas, RE.C_to_meas, RE.C_road_length
      ) AS RE
  ) AS RE
 WHERE RE.leftover_length > 0--Filter out Events that had their entire Segments overlapped by a Later Event(s).
 ORDER BY RE.road_id, RE.year DESC, RE.event_id
```

**SQL Fiddle:**
     http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2880b/1

**Added Rules/Assumptions/Clarifications:**
1.) Allow for the possibility `event_id` and `road_id` could be Guid's or created out-of-order,
     so do not script assuming higher or lower values give meaning to the relationship of records.
     *For Example:*
       An ID of 1 and and ID of 2 does not guarantee the ID of 2 is the most recent one (and vice-versa).
       This is so the solution will be more general and less "hacky".
2.) Filter out Events that had their entire Segments overlapped by a Later Event(s).
     *For Example:*
       If 2008 had work on 20-50 and 2009 had work on 10-60,
       then the Event for 2008 would be filtered out because its entire Segment was rehashed in 2009.

**Additional Test Data:**
To ensure solutions are not tailored to only the DataSet given,
     I have added a `road_id` of **6** to the original DataSet, in order to hit a few more fringe-cases.

```
INSERT INTO road_events (event_id, road_id, year, from_meas, to_meas, total_road_length) VALUES (16,6,2012,0,100,100);
INSERT INTO road_events (event_id, road_id, year, from_meas, to_meas, total_road_length) VALUES (17,6,2013,68,69,100);
INSERT INTO road_events (event_id, road_id, year, from_meas, to_meas, total_road_length) VALUES (18,6,2014,65,66,100);
INSERT INTO road_events (event_id, road_id, year, from_meas, to_meas, total_road_length) VALUES (19,6,2015,62,63,100);
INSERT INTO road_events (event_id, road_id, year, from_meas, to_meas, total_road_length) VALUES (20,6,2016,50,60,100);
INSERT INTO road_events (event_id, road_id, year, from_meas, to_meas, total_road_length) VALUES (21,6,2017,30,40,100);
INSERT INTO road_events (event_id, road_id, year, from_meas, to_meas, total_road_length) VALUES (22,6,2017,20,55,100);
INSERT INTO road_events (event_id, road_id, year, from_meas, to_meas, total_road_length) VALUES (23,6,2018,0,25,100);
```

**Results:** (*with the **8** Additional Records I added in **Green***)
[image]

**Database Version:**
This Solution is Oracle and SQL-Server Agnostic:
     It Should Work in both **SS2008**+ and **Oracle 12c**+.

This question is tagged with *Oracle 12c*, but there is no online-fiddle I may use without signing up,
     so I tested it in SQL-Server - but the same syntax should work in both.
I rely on `Cross-Apply` and `Outer-Apply` for most of my queries.
Oracle introduced these "Joins" in 12c:
     https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/lateral-inline-views-cross-apply-and-outer-apply-joins-12cr1

**Simplified and Performant:**
This uses:
     • No Correlated Subqueries.
     • No Recursion.
     • No CTE's.
     • No Unions.
     • No User Functions.

**Indexes:**
I read in one of your comments you had asked about Indexes.
I would add 1-Column Indexes for each the main Fields you will be searching and grouping on:
     `road_id`, `event_id`, and `year`.
You could see if this index would help you any (I don't know how you plan to use the data):
     **Key Fields:** `road_id`, `event_id`, `year`
     **Include:**    `from_meas`, `to_meas`

**Title:**
You may want to consider Renaming the Title of this Question to something more searchable like:
     "*Aggregate Overlapping Segments to Measure Effective Length*".
This would allow the solution to be easier to find for helping others with similar problems.

**Other Thoughts:**
Something like this would be useful in Tallying up the Overall-Time spent on something
     with overlapping Start and Stop timestamps.

Answer (score 3):

This finds expands the table to produce a row for each mile of each road, and simply takes the `MAX` year. We can just then `COUNT` the number of rows to produce the event_length.

It produces the table exactly as you specified above.

Note: I ran this query against SQL Server. You could use `LEAST` instead of `SELECT MIN(event_length) FROM (VALUES...)` in Oracle I think.

```
WITH NumberRange(result) AS 
(
    SELECT 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT result + 1
    FROM   NumberRange 
    WHERE  result < 301 --Max length of any road
),
CurrentRoadEventLength(road_id, [year], event_length) AS
(
    SELECT road_id, [year], COUNT(*) AS event_length
    FROM   (
            SELECT re.road_id, n.result, MAX(re.[year]) as [year]
            FROM   road_events re INNER JOIN NumberRange n 
                   ON (    re.from_meas <= n.result 
                       AND re.to_meas > n.result
                      )
            GROUP BY re.road_id, n.result
           ) events_per_mile
    GROUP BY road_id, [year]
)
SELECT re.event_id, re.road_id, re.[year], re.total_road_length, 
       (SELECT MIN(event_length) FROM (VALUES (re.to_meas - re.from_meas), (cre.event_length)) AS EventLengths(event_length))
FROM   road_events re INNER JOIN CurrentRoadEventLength cre
       ON (    re.road_id = cre.road_id
           AND re.[year] = cre.[year]
          )
ORDER BY re.event_id, re.road_id
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 301) --Max length of any road
```